# Bootcamp: How do you reboot from Windows to Windows via script in OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, windows

I'm asking this because I think it would be incredibly useful to myself and other Bootcamp users. I currently have my default boot drive set to restart to my Mac partition and already have a script for restarting into Windows from Mac.

However, my current problem is restarting from Windows into Windows while maintaining Mac as the default restart via a script. I found an older post about a [script](http://lifehacker.com/5720007/reboot-your-mac-into-windows-from-windows-with-a-batch-script) that I tried but it did not work even with SIP(System Integrity Protection) disabled.

On another note, has anyone found a script that works to restart into Windows without disabling SIP?